# If-condition is not executed in a for-loop when scraping data from kworb.net

Tags: python, if-statement, web-scraping

I need to collect data on the countries where artists are streamed most frequently on Spotify. To do that, I am using [this source](https://kworb.net/spotify/artists.html) that contains a list of 10.000 artists.

So the aim of my code is to create a table with two columns:

1. artist name;
2. country where the artist is streamed the most.

I wrote a code (see below) that gets this information from each artist's personal page (here is an example for [Drake](https://kworb.net/spotify/artist/3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4.html)). An artist's name is taken from the title of a page and the country code -- from table column heading preceded by the column titled "Global". For some artists, there is no column titled "Global" and I need to account for this condition. And here is where my problems comes in.

I am using the following if-condition:

```
if "<th>Global</th>" not in soup2.find_all('table')[0].find_all('th'):
    Country = soup2.find_all('table')[0].find_all('th')[4].text
else:
    Country = soup2.find_all('table')[0].find_all('th')[5].text
country.append(Country)
```

But only the first condition is executed, where the code extracts the text from the 4th column. Alternatively, I tried the reverse condition:

```
if "<th>Global</th>" in soup2.find_all('table')[0].find_all('th'):
    Country = soup2.find_all('table')[0].find_all('th')[5].text
else:
    Country = soup2.find_all('table')[0].find_all('th')[4].text
country.append(Country)
```

But the code still extracts the text from the 4th column, even if I want it to extract it from the 5th column when the 4th column is titled "Global".

This reproducible code is run for a subset of artists, for whom there is a column titled "Global" (e.g. [LANY](https://kworb.net/spotify/artist/49tQo2QULno7gxHutgccqF.html)) and for whom there is none (e.g. [Henrique & Diego](https://kworb.net/spotify/artist/1D6vAeVUcgMbSx80IA3Zun.html))(#391 to #395 as of June 16, 2019):

```py
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

response1 = get('https://kworb.net/spotify/artists.html', headers = headers)

soup1 = bs(response1.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup1.find_all('table')[0]
rows = table.find_all('tr')[391:396]    #selected subset of 10.000 artists

artist = []
country = []

for row in rows:
    artist_url = row.find('a')['href']

    response2 = get('https://kworb.net/spotify/' + artist_url)

    sleep(randint(8,15))

    soup2 = bs(response2.text, 'html.parser')

    Artist = soup2.find('title').text[:-24]
    artist.append(Artist)

    if "<th>Global</th>" not in soup2.find_all('table')[0].find_all('th'):    #problem suspected in this if-condition
        Country = soup2.find_all('table')[0].find_all('th')[4].text
    else:
        Country = soup2.find_all('table')[0].find_all('th')[5].text
    country.append(Country)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Artist': artist,
                   'Country': country
})

print(df)
```

As a result, I get the following:

```
    Artist           Country
0   YNW Melly        Global
1   Henrique & Diego BR
2   LANY             Global
3   Parson James     Global
4   ANAVITÃRIA       BR
```

While the actual output, as of June 16, 2019, should be:

```
    Artist              Country
0   YNW Melly           US
1   Henrique & Diego    BR
2   LANY                PH
3   Parson James        US
4   ANAVITÃRIA          BR
```

I suspect the wrong if-condition for the variable `country`. I would appreciate any help with regard to that.

Comment: Don't you need to look at the entire table of tracks to determine which countries have the most streams?

Comment: @QHarr, if I understand the logic of that table correctly, the number of streams increases as you go from the right to the left. For example, [this artist](https://kworb.net/spotify/artist/48sLioddyaXkuhyHXSkpsB.html) seems to be most popular/streamed in the US. And if you look at the [streams of his most popular track](https://kworb.net/spotify/track/4iZPNYqzI2L0uwuUKun7Aa.html), it indeed appears to be so. I might be mistaken though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compare bs4 object with string.
Need first get text from each found object then compare with string:

replace:

```
if "<th>Global</th>" not in soup2.find_all('table')[0].find_all('th'):
```

with:

```
# get text options from html
found_options = [item.text for item in soup2.find_all('table')[0].find_all('th')]

if "Global" not in found_options:
```

Output:

```
             Artist Country
0         YNW Melly      US
1  Henrique & Diego      BR
2              LANY      PH
3      Parson James      US
4       ANAVITÃRIA      BR
```